# Usage of DataKeyNames in an ASP.NET GridView?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

In which cases should I use a GridView's property `DataKeyNames`?

Why are multiple columns/fields allowed here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Gets or sets an array that contains the names of the primary key fields for the items displayed in a GridView control.

[GridView.DataKeyNames Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx)

[GridView.DataKeys Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

It keeps the `primary key` fields or `id` field of data table, which gridview shows.

According to MSDN

> Gets or sets an array that contains
>   the names of the primary key fields
>   for the items displayed in a GridView
>   control.